# SQL to LINQ with outer joins and count

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying to write the LINQ statement for the following OUTER JOIN with COUNT but can't seem to work it out..

My LINQ skills aren't what they should be yet so any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

The SQL statement in question is:

```
SELECT b.Id,

   b.Text,

   b.Active,

   COUNT(u.BusinessArea_Id)

 FROM dbo.[User] AS u RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.BusinessArea AS b ON b.Id = u.BusinessArea_Id

 GROUP BY b.Id, b.Text, Active
 ORDER BY b.Id
```

Comment: Have you made a start. what are these object called ? Please share what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a linq like this:

```
var res = (from ba in businessAreas
           let count = users.Count(u => u.BusinessArea_Id == ba.Id)
           orderby ba.Id
           select new {ba.Id, ba.Text, ba.Active, Count = count}
          ).ToList();
```